# Motor de SQL detenido

Tags: sql-server

Alguno de ustedes ha visto este error:

> The log scan number (35:295:1) passed to log scan in database 'model'
>   is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log
>   file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error
>   occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise,
>   restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during
>   startup.

Este error aparece por que el Motor de **SQL** esta detenido, y de ninguna forma he podido hacer que funcione.

Al querer conectarme al motor me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: tienes backups cierto?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo he hecho es:

1. Presiono el boton de inicio y escribo sql.
2. Te muestra **sql server configuration manager**
3. Presiona click derecho sobre ello y lo corres como administrador
4. Te aparecerán los servicios de sql server y te apareceran stopped o detener.
5. Le das click derecho a sql server Agent y pones stop o detener.
6. Luego le das start o encender a cada uno de ellos, lo tienes que colocar en start o encender.

Saludos!

Comment: No sirve nada de eso, ya lo he hecho y servicio que no iniciar es el SQL Server.

Comment: hazlo con cada uno de los servicios que te aparece ahí?

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta los siguientes comandos y actualiza tu pregunta con el resultado que te den:

```
ALTER DATABASE nombreDeTuBaseDeDatos SET EMERGENCY  
DBCC CHECKDB (nombreDeTuBaseDeDatos) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

Actualizaré la respuesta de acuerdo a lo que encuentres.

Comment: Donde puedo ejecutar los comando? No me abre ninguna base. Donde puedo agregar una imagen?

Comment: Aquí hermano: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Por cierto, has defragmentado el disco duro? Una vez me pasó que al realizarle un defragmentado, la BD se rayó quedando corrupta, para buena suerte todo se solucionó sin pérdida de información

Comment: Sube tu imagen a imgur.com como comentario y te ayudo a editar tu pregunta. También ten los logs a la mano, es mejor copiar y pegar letras que imágenes en este caso porque es más sencillo de leer. Saludos

Comment: Pues no sabria decirte si se ejecuto una Defragmentación. El detalle es que como les comento cuando voy a SQL Management Studio el motor esta detenido y lo intento echar a andar y pues aparece un error. Y no es solo en un equipo es en varios.

Comment: No se como hacer mención o etiquetas, para quien me pregunto, no no tengo respaldos, intente copiar las Master y las Model de mi equipo a el equipo que me manda el error, osea elimine las bases corruptas del SQL dañado y pegue unas que no tienen error pero ni aun asi deja de aparecer

Comment: Lograste acceder al sqlcmd?

Comment: Las menciones se hacen con un @nombreDeUsuario

Comment: no no supe como acceder a sqlcmd otra cosa una vez que entro a imgur.com por donde se las comparto?

Comment: En el botón inicio, todos los programas y busca: sqlcmd con respecto a la imagen, agrega como comentario y te ayudo a editar tu pregunta con la imagen

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Ew29M

Comment: listo, imagen editada, por cierto, lograste acceder por sqlcmd?

Comment: Gracias amigo, si ya pude abrirlo!!

Comment: de nada amigo, ahora a darle con los comandos! espero se pueda solucionar pronto :D

Comment: Pregunta entonces?? Lo que me quieren decir es que... No arranca mi SQL por que la base de datos a la quiero entrar esta dañada?

Comment: correcto, por eso quiero saber qué información te sale luego de ejecutar los comandos mencionados. //Luiggi, Miquell, JuanM luego translado los comentarios a una sala para mantener el orden en el sitio :D

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/nRQ5A aqui el primer error.

Comment: en qué momento te sale ese error?

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

1. detengo los servicios.
2. voy a la carpeta data de sql y copio en otra ubicación todos los archivos de las bases de datos.
3. desinstalo el sql y lo vuelvo a instalar.

Esto me ha pasado varias veces en windows 7 y windows server 2008 y al parecer (no estoy 100% seguro) hay una actualización de windows que detiene los servicios y luego no hay manera de reiniciarlos de nuevo mas que reinstalando.